# cleos push action is not working on multihost peer node

Tags: smart-contract, nodeos, cleos, wallet

I have a setup of multinode, one `genesis` node and another host node `inita` connected to the `genesis` node. `Nodeos` is running on both hosts. Genesis node is producing blocks and `inita` is receiving them. I created wallet, account and deployed `hello` smart contract on genesis node. After this, called:

```
cleos --url http://genesis_ip:8889 push action hello hi '["abc"]' -p abc@active
```

This works fine. Then I call this same command on `inita` node:

```
cleos --url http://inita_ip:8889 push action hello hi '["abc"]' -p abc@active
```

This gives error:

```
Error 3120006: No available wallet
Ensure that you have created a wallet and have it open
Error Details:
You don't have any wallet!
```

Whereas, accounts are accessible on `inita`.
Should I need to create the same wallet on `inita` peer node also? Can't this deployed contract will get access on other peer nodes who are receiving the blocks? I was assuming that once the wallets are created on genesis node, no need of the same procedures on peer nodes. Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in that you need to create a wallet on `inita` node as well as on the genesis node.
Actions can only be pushed to the blockchain from a location where the private key is accessible. The most common way to do this is to store the private key in a wallet and then unlock that wallet before pushing the action to the chain.
You set up a wallet and imported to private key on the genesis server, and therefore you can push actions on that server, however if you want to push actions from a different server then you need to create a wallet there and import the private key again on that server as well.